# H2 Database, merge into table using Java CSVREAD

Tags: java, sql, database, csv, h2

Good day! I have the following codes to connect to the H2 database and perform queries using Java. However, only the CALL CSVWRITE is working for me.

Here is my code:

```
public static Result tagImport() {
    String user = session("username");
    Connection connection = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:h2:file:~/data/db", "sa", "");
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement
                .executeQuery("CALL CSVWRITE('textfiles/tags.csv', 'SELECT * FROM TAG');");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            resultSet.close();
            statement.close();
            connection.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
        return ok(dbSuccess.render(user));
}

public static Result tagExport() {
    String user = session("username");
    Connection connection = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:h2:file:~/data/db", "sa", "");
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery("MERGE INTO TAG (SELECT * FROM CSVREAD('textfiles/tags.csv'));");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            resultSet.close();
            statement.close();
            connection.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
        return ok(dbSuccess.render(user));
}
```

As you can see, the only difference is the query to be executed. I have used the same approach for both but it doesn't seem to work for the tagExport function. I just want to connect to the database again and insert into the table the csv file that I have created with the tagImport function. Kindly help. Thanks!

Comment: Could you try `MERGE INTO TAG SELECT * FROM CSVREAD('textfiles/tags.csv')`?

Comment: thanks but the query still won't work. i really couldn't identify the problem.

Comment: It works for me. You need to provide more info: the `create table` statement of the `tag` table, the error message and stack trace, and some data.

Comment: I think i have figured it out. I turned the resultSet variable into an int and replaced the statement.executeQuery with statement.executeUpdate and it worked. Thank you for your help though! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `MERGE` statement, you need to use `Statement.executeUpdate()` instead of `executeQuery()`

Comment: yes. it is definitely the solution for this. in addition, i have implemented the above code with this: `ResultSet resultSet = null;` to `int resultSet = 0;` because the executeUpdate() returns an int value. that would be all. thanks!

Comment: by the way, sorry i can't vote up your answer. i don't have 15 reputations yet. thanks again!